# Assembler messages -> Error : register number out of range

Tags: assembly, compiler-errors, esp32, xtensa

I am trying to use the instruction 
`mula.dd.ll.ldinc m3 , a5 , m0  ,m1`
in my assembly code 
on ESP32 which has xtensa LX6 processors.

It doesn't produce error for other instructions, but for this particular instruction it is producing `register number out of range`.

I am using a2-a4 for taking in arguments in the assembly code and using other registers for my purposes. The xtensa LX6 processors have 16 (AR , 32 bit) general purpose registers

---

I have also tried reducing the argument number passed to the assembly function and used

`mula.dd.ll.ldinc m3 , a3 , m0  ,m1`

but it provides same error

This syntax is exactly as it is used in the Instruction set.

```
mula.dd.ll.ldinc m3 , a3 , m0  ,m1 // the instruction multiplies m0 * m1 and adds it to the accumulator and then loads data at a3+4 into m3 ( +4 is because of auto increment )
```

Answer (score 1):

> This syntax is exactly as it is used in the Instruction set.
>
> ```
> mula.dd.ll.ldinc m3 , a3 , m0  ,m1
> ```

No, not exactly. The ISA book chapter for this opcode says the following:

```
MULA.DD.*.LDINC mw, as, mx, my

The mx operand can designate either MAC16 register m0 or m1.
The my operand can designate either MAC16 register m2 or m3.
```

so you cannot have m1 as the last register argument.